# How to install Java and Maven in Mac Yosemite?

Tags: java, macos, maven, java-8

I am new in MAC OS World. I have a new laptop. I've installed Java JDK from oracle web site. Java 8 is correctly installed. 
The command `java -version` works 
I install maven :
1. I've downloaded the maven tar.gz and extract it on the Users directory.
I create the file .bash_profile with the content :

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/dgeorges/Tools/apache-maven-3.2.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

2. Then i ran mvn -version and i have the following error :
   Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
   We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java

How to see the java installed directory ?
Why mac ox search on /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java ?

Thanks

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home` is a _command_ that tells you the right value to put in `JAVA_HOME`, not the Java home directory itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While apple itself recommends to set the `JAVA_HOME` to: `/usr/libexec/java_home` it doesn't work for maven. You have to set it to `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`. This executes and returns the value of OSX's current Java home dir.

So to do that, you have to update your JAVA_HOME. So, open the Terminal and type the following into it:

```
$ vim .bash_profile 

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

$ source .bash_profile
```

Now maven should recognize your Java-version.